# pydantic Optional Form returns 422 on post when form is missing

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

How can I get an optional Form,

```py
@app.post("/config", include_in_schema=False)
async def postconfig(request: Request,
    gitlabtoken:str = Form(...),
    gitlaburl:str = Form(...),
    projectids:str = Form(...),
    jobscopes:str = Form(...),
    filter:str = Form(...),
    blacklist:str = Form(...),
    historyurls:Optional[str] = Form(...)
):
    """ update config fields in mem """
```

When I post updates with historyurls="", it fails passing pydantic returning 422:

```
{"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["body","historyurls"],"msg":"Field required","input":null,"url":"https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing"}]}
```

I can add something to historyurls, or I can also use pydantic.ValidationError, but should not the Optional take care of this?

Comment: `...` makes the field required, you probably want `Form(None)` instead: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#required-with-ellipsis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make historyurls accept None by explicitly setting None as the default value:

```
historyurls: str = Form(None)
```

or,

```
historyurls: Optional[str] = Form(None)
```

Comment: Thanks so, I need to verify both sides of the equation. Tested and now it works exellent